# About the word たまわぴ

Tags: words

I have no idea what this word means and I cannot find it in the dictionary. My guess is it could be an adverb but really I have no idea.

I stumbled in this in the following sentence:

> 今回の出版に関してご配慮を**たまわぴ**感謝にたえません。

This is a sentence for a practice test for N1 found [here](http://japanesetest4you.com/japanese-language-proficiency-test-jlpt-n1-grammar-exercise-3/). Not knowing the word also makes it hard to translate the sentence properly.

Comment: 「たまわぴ」ww 新しいギャル語かと思ったww

Answer (score 2):

This must be a typo of 'たまわり'.
'たまわる' means to receive.

Comment: Makes sense, it is probably as you say. So how would you translate the whole sentence?

Comment: ^ たまわる（賜る）is the humble form (謙譲語) of もらう, so ご配慮をたまわり感謝にたえません means 配慮してもらって、感謝に堪えない/とても感謝している, "I cannot thank you enough / I cannot be too grateful to you for your consideration/concern"